# GameplayKit Pathfinding with obstacles and agents

Tags: sprite-kit, path-finding, agent, ios9, gameplay-kit

I've been searching for days about this new framework and trying to make usage of some of it's funcionalities,
but... there're some things that are not fitting together for me, the demobot source code isn't helping at some points, 
I miss some kind of simple tutorial but here goes my main doubts:

```
let obstacles = scene["obstacle"]
polygonObstacles = SKNode.obstaclesFromNodePhysicsBodies(obstacles)
graph = GKObstacleGraph(obstacles: polygonObstacles, bufferRadius: 60.0)


func drawGraph() {
    for node in graph.nodes as! [GKGraphNode2D] {
        for destination in node.connectedNodes as! [GKGraphNode2D] {
            let points = [CGPoint(node.position), CGPoint(destination.position)]
            let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(points: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>(points), count: 2)
            shapeNode.strokeColor = SKColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
            shapeNode.lineWidth = 5.0
            shapeNode.zPosition = 3
            scene.addChild(shapeNode)
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I try to draw this graph and see the connections, I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6HiG.jpg
I find it really weird, anywhere I put my obstacles, even in low numbers, the left-corner portion of the screen have always more connections(the radius don't have influence on that)

I don't use GKComponents on my game, but I tried to run some GKAgents2D to hunt the player, like this:

```
func calculateBehaviorForAgents(){

  let mainCharacterPosition = float2(scene.mainCharacter.position)
  let mainCharacterGraphNode = GKGraphNode2D(point: mainCharacterPosition)
  graph.connectNodeUsingObstacles(mainCharacterGraphNode)
  for i in 0...monsters.count-1{
     let monster = monsters[i]
     let agent = agents[i]

     let behavior = GKBehavior()

     let monsterPosition = float2(monster.position)
     let monsterGraphNode = GKGraphNode2D(point: monsterPosition)
     graph.connectNodeUsingObstacles(monsterGraphNode)

     let pathNodes = graph.findPathFromNode(monsterGraphNode, toNode: mainCharacterGraphNode) as! [GKGraphNode2D]
     let path = GKPath(graphNodes: pathNodes, radius: 00.0)

     let followPathGoal = GKGoal(toFollowPath: path, maxPredictionTime: 1.0, forward: true)
     behavior.setWeight(1.0, forGoal: followPathGoal)

     let stayOnPathGoal = GKGoal(toStayOnPath: path, maxPredictionTime: 1.0)
     behavior.setWeight(1.0, forGoal: stayOnPathGoal)

     agent.behavior = behavior

     graph.removeNodes([monsterGraphNode])
  }
  graph.removeNodes([mainCharacterGraphNode])

}
```

Now when I call the updateWithDeltaTime method, his delegate methods:
func agentWillUpdate(agent: GKAgent){}
func agentDidUpdate(agent: GKAgent){}
give me unexpected values for the agents, it's position doesn't make any sense, with giant numbers that leads to outside of the battlefield

But I saw that the his velocity vector were making sense, so I matched it to my monster and updated the agent to the monster's position

```
func updateWithDeltaTime(currentTime : CFTimeInterval){

  for i in 0...monsters.count-1{

  let agent = agents[i]
  let monster = monsters[i]

  monster.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(CGFloat(agent.velocity.x), CGFloat(agent.velocity.y))

  agent.updateWithDeltaTime(currentTime)
  agent.position = float2(monster.position)
  monster.gameSceneUpdate(currentTime)

}
```

Now I was getting some results, but it's far away from what I want:
**The monsters are not following the character to the edges or the right-top portion of screen**, I remove their points from the graph but **after** make a path for them to follow (the image doesn't have this points, but they exists).
Apparently because there was no path leading to there, remember the image?

**The question is: how to make this agent system to work?**

Maybe I'm totally wrong at the usage of agents, goals and even the graphs! I read the documentation but I still can't make it right
And more...
At first, the monster were not avoid obstacles, even with GKGoals like "avoidObstacles", passing the same PolygonObstacles,
but when I change

```
graph.connectNodeUsingObstacles(mainCharacterGraphNode)
graph.connectNodeUsingObstacles(monsterGraphNode)
```

to

```
graph.connectNodeUsingObstacles(mainCharacterGraphNode, ignoringObstacles: polygonObstacles)
graph.connectNodeUsingObstacles(monsterGraphNode, ignoringObstacles: polygonObstacles)
```

it worked! o.O

I really need some help, thank you all :D!

Comment: You did not ask a question, and please keep questions to a single topic. From what I can tell, there could be problems with the fact that GK is still beta, the way you draw lines, how you setup the agents, or the fact that you're matching physics with agents (which is not impossible but tricky). Try to isolate your question into specific problem areas and (for each, unless closely related) ask a question about that specifically.

Comment: Sorry for the long topic, but yeah, I tried to expose all my doubts on the topic, the main question is how can I get this system to work better, how to make the agent to properly follow a path, avoid obstacles and hunt a player for all along a big scene.
I expect someone who understand this agent system and tell me the right way to manage them :/

Comment: From my own experiments I found it really tricky to get good, consistent behavior. There's a lot of tweaking involved. Suggestion: start simple and introduce new goals one at a time. For isntance, get the agent to follow the path strictly. Then loosen it up. Then add obstacle avoidance. Etc etc. You'll need to build several test cases, testing individual situations.

Comment: what is the array of agents? GKAgents2D? Sorry if that sounds stupid, I'm totally new to GameplayKit